# Multiple "useFetch"-calls lead to Error Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a vueJS component created and it worked fine. When i now added a second "useFetch" call in my `<script setup>` tag it resulted in this error-message:

```
A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably not a Nuxt bug. Find out more at `https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports#vue-and-nuxt-composables`.
    at Module.useNuxtApp (/Users/user/Code/Personal/universityCheckIn/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/nuxt.js:216:13)
    at Module.useAsyncData (/Users/user/Code/Personal/universityCheckIn/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/composables/asyncData.js:26:38)
    at Module.useFetch (/Users/user/Code/Personal/universityCheckIn/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/composables/fetch.js:63:43)
    at checkIfCheckedIn (/Users/user/Code/Personal/universityCheckIn/pages/check-in.vue:51:50)
    at init (/Users/user/Code/Personal/universityCheckIn/pages/check-in.vue:75:30)
```

My `<script setup>` part, that is relevant looks like this:

```
<script setup>
  // General Values
  const alreadyCheckedIn = ref(false);
  const showModal = ref(false);
  const lecture = ref(null);

  // Modal Values
  const lectureName = ref("");
  const startTime = ref("");

  // Error handling
  const displayError = ref(false);
  const errorMessage = ref("Please fill in all fields.");

  // Fetch lecture data
  async function fetchLectureData() {
    const lectureDateObj = new Date();
    const lectureDateStr = lectureDateObj.toISOString().split("T")[0];
    const { data } = await useFetch("/api/lecture", {
      method: "GET",
      query: {
        lectureDate: lectureDateStr,
        groupId: 1, //TODO: get the group id from the user
      },
    });

    if (data.value.statusCode === 404) {
      return;
    }
    return data.value.body ? await JSON.parse(data.value.body) : null;
  }

  async function checkIfCheckedIn() {
    const lectureDateObj = new Date();
    const lectureDateStr = lectureDateObj.toISOString().split("T")[0];
    const { data } = await useFetch("/api/check-in", {
      method: "GET",
      query: {
        lectureDate: lectureDateStr,
        userId: 1, //TODO: get the user id from the user
        groupId: 1, //TODO: get the group id from the user
      },
    });

    if (data.value.statusCode === 404) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  // Initialize lecture data
  async function init() {
    const lectureFromDB = await fetchLectureData();
    if (lectureFromDB) {
      lecture.value = lectureFromDB;
      lecture.value.start_time = new Date(
        lecture.value.start_time
      ).toLocaleTimeString("de-DE", { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" });
    }
    alreadyCheckedIn.value = await checkIfCheckedIn();
  }
  init();
.
.
.
```

The `fetchLectureData()` function was there first and everything worked fine. Then i added the `checkIfCheckedIn()` function the described error was thrown.

I tried if it was dependent on the `checkIfCheckedIn()` function and removed the `fetchLectureData()` function (so just one "useFetch" call existed") and everything worked again. So the issue is not dependent on the function itself, but on the fact that there are two "useFetch"-calls.

If it is not possible the way i tried to use the "useFetch", how can i make two independent API calls when loading the page?

Comment: You can't reassign to a const.  `const alreadyCheckedIn = ref(false);` ... `alreadyCheckedIn = await checkIfCheckedIn();` - did you mean to assign it to alreadyCheckedIn.value?

Comment: @James yes, this was a typo resulting from my debugging process. I updated the code snippet. But the described error wasn't resulting from this mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I found following in the documentation "On top of that, you must use them synchronously - that is, you cannot use await before calling a composable [...]"

So, because both were async operations where one blocks the other, i called "await" before a composable and this results in an error.
I used the following approach to avoid calling one await before the other useFetch:

```js
Promise.all([fetchLectureData(), checkIfCheckedIn()])
      .then(([lectureFromDB, checkedIn]) => {
        if (lectureFromDB) {
          lecture.value = lectureFromDB;
          lecture.value.start_time = new Date(
            lecture.value.start_time
          ).toLocaleTimeString("de-DE", { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" });
        }
        alreadyCheckedIn.value = checkedIn;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```